# A 10Gig NIC card

Tags: networking, server, pcie, network-adapter, home-electronics

I'm from India.
Please recommend:

- a 10Gig NIC card, or
- a website that can be used to find info about this.

### Specification/Requirements:

- Supported speeds: 10Gig
- To be used for PCIe x1 Lane
- Copper, so RJ45 jack.
- Available in abundance.
- Longer EOL.

### Software:

- Better EOL
- Readily available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INTEL X710-DA2**

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/83964/intel-ethernet-converged-network-adapter-x710da2.html

you will need the corresponding SFP to plug a rj45 cable in

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000007045/ethernet-products/700-series-network-adapters-up-to-40gbe.html

> your comment below: *I'm actually looking for x1 lane, these only support x8 lanes*

```
https://www.cgdirector.com/guide-to-pcie-lanes/

PCIe Bandwith   Transfer Rate   Bandwidth x1 (per lane)   x4          x8           x16
PCIe 1.0        2.5GT/s         250 MB/s                  1.00 GB/s   2.00 GB/s    4.00 GB/s
PCIe 2.0        5GT/s           500 MB/s                  2.00 GB/s   4.00 GB/s    8.00 GB/s
PCIe 3.0        8GT/s           984.6 MB/s                3.94 GB/s   7.88 GB/s    15.75 GB/s
PCIe 4.0        16GT/s          1969 MB/s                 7.88 GB/s   15.75 GB/s   31.51 GB/s
```

you said a 10gig nic card, to get 10gbps you cannot do that with just 1 pcie lane.  The X710-da2 nic card is pcie 3.0 x8 lane, shown as 7.88 GB/sec bandwidth which is 7.88 * 8 = 63 gbps.  If you had a x1 pcie 3.0 nic card then 0.9846 * 8 = 7.87 gbps so while the NIC card could transmit across cat6/7 cable at 10gig speeds the motherboard wouldn't be able to send it data fast enough over just one pcie lane.  So I don't think you will find a pcie 3.0/4.0 x1 NIC that is 10 GbE.

And a quick search I don't really see any PCIe 4.0 10GbE NIC's, and what little I do see refers to them being x4.  Also network is duplex so also divide by 2.  so a pcie 4.0 x1 @ 1969 MB/s = 15.7 gbps but for duplex network that'll max out at 7.87 gbps.  So at best you might find a pcie 4.0 x4 nic that's 10GbE it would at least I think be physically possible.... whether anyone ever makes one I dunno.  I suspect they would simply standardize on NIC's using 8 pcie lanes, especially when NIC's now almost always have more than one rj45 port.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm actually looking for x1 lane, these only support x8 lanes

Comment: https://www.overclock.net/threads/10gbe-in-pci-e-4-0-x1-has-anyone-tried.1752386/

Comment: Thanks,I do have a x16 port, So, I've started looking into the x500 series-based controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with these a while. I picked up a pair of X540-T2  - they're 'server' cards, so run a little hot, though there's a version with a fan. The T suffix means native copper support so you don't need a SFP.

They're PCIe 2.1 x8 for TWO ports, and you can run a single port at full speed (tested by speed test) on a x4 slot with no issue. The x550 is a newer version that'll work on x4, but I've not found them cheap on the secondary market. They're about 90usd + shipping on aliexpress, but prices vary wildly - as of 2023. they're down to as low as ~20 USD or less. They are EOL but the current intel drivers support them. They *won't* downgrade to 2.5 or 5 gbps, so you'll need a 10gig copper capable switch or connect them directly. On windows the drivers are *excellent* and easy to use, and as older cards they're well understood. They have a mild tendancy to overheat, so run it on a system that's capable of cooling it. While both these cards are "obsolete", they're common and supported with current drivers.

I've *not* tried it yet, but most modern low cost 10Gbps cards are based off Aquantia chips - they'll work with the 'slower' multigigabit standards and are about the same price as my x540 for a single port. They do PCIe x4 and seem a better option in quite a few ways. I believe asus sells one, as well as various chinese vendors like comfast.

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/58954/intel-ethernet-converged-network-adapter-x540t2.html

Comment: Reflected in my answer. They're still supported by current drivers, and frankly - if not for the aquantia cards dropping in price since I got em earlier this year, probably the best value. You also save a bit on getting a SFP with all of these options

Comment: intel says it's pci 2.1e and x8, and other than being *discontinued* it's probably a best buy 10GbE card that does regular rj45 cat 6 versus needing an SFP like you said.  The only discrepancy is the guys request for a pcie x1 10gbe card which i don't think is physically possible, if he wants 10gbe i think it'll be doing x8 pcie at minimum.

Comment: Nope. Best we have now is x4. And yeah, it's basically the current equivalent to those mellenox cards folks were getting cheap a few years back. Old but still usable

Comment: Thanks for answering, I got the x540-T2 as well. It's x8(Turns out I had an x16 port in production so, having x8 is not an issue.) Well now building driver support for this. Let's see how it works.

Thanks again